# How to customize the fingerprint prompt bottom dialog working on Android emulator in react-native-biometrics

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, android-biometric-prompt

developers,
I am working on a react native project that requires faceid login functionality.
Thanks to the libs and sample codes in the github repo, I implemented on my app very easily.
However, it displays the default bottom dialog when requiring the user to pass faceID auth in the android emulator.
react-native-biometrics

```
import ReactNativeBiometrics from 'react-native-biometrics';
//...
ReactNativeBiometrics.createSignature({
      promptMessage: ' ',
      payload: payload
    })
      .then((resultObject) => {
        const { success, signature } = resultObject;
        if (success) {
          setMaskActive(true);
        }
      });
```

[image]
how can I remove the prompt dialog, but still keep calling ReactNativeBiometrics.createSignature() function?
Thank you.

Comment: [github issue by OP](https://github.com/SelfLender/react-native-biometrics/issues/179)

Comment: So, do you want to implement only facial id with this package?

Comment: yes, but must be work on both types of device.